# Superfish menu adding two effects

Tags: jquery, html

I am using Superfish menu . i need to implement two effects simuntanesoly 
vertical as well as navbar. 
i added this code

```
 jQuery('#superfish-1 li a').hover(function() {
  jQuery('#superfish-1').addClass('sf-vertical sf-navbar');
});
```

But it is picking only navbar effect..

can anybody tell me how to do this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('#superfish-1 li a').hover(function() {// worlk on mouse over
 if(! jQuery('#superfish-1').hasClass('sf-vertical sf-navbar'))     
 {
    jQuery('#superfish-1').addClass('sf-vertical sf-navbar');
  }
 });
```

reference **[.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)**

Comment: i dont need mouseout effect.